# __EVENTTARGET is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, jquery

I have a web page(.aspx), on which I'm loading some user control by jQuery ajax. 
Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/GetGrid",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                 $('#divAjaxGridViewContainer').html(result.d);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

In WebService.asmx.cs Web Service I have a GetGrid WebMethod which generates and returns the html of user control, that contains grid view. Here is the code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetPage(object[] criteria)
{
    Page page = new Page {ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled};

    AjaxGridView grid = (AjaxGridView)page.LoadControl("~/Controls/AjaxGridView.ascx");
    grid.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled;

    grid.BindData(criteria);

    HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm {ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled};

    form.Controls.Add(grid);

    page.Controls.Add(form);

    string result = String.Empty;

    using (StringWriter output = new StringWriter())
    {
        page.Server.Execute(page, output, false);
        result = output.ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

AjaxGridView is a user control, that contains a GridView, and binds it to some data depending on some criteria with BindData(criteria) public method.

All this code works fine. I've used this technique several times and it used to work fine.

This time, after loading the html from service onto the page, clicking the controls that should make autopostback (such as asp:Button, asp:DropDownList, asp:CheckBoxList), throws the following js esception:
**__EVENTTARGET is undefined**

on this part of code:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I've figured out something.
theForm is being set like this:

```
var theForm = document.forms['ctl00'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl00;
}
```

As I have form in my dynamically generated html, theForm is referring to that form, which doesn't have __EVENTTARGET. 
I decided to remove form tag from generated html in service:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
    Regex frmOpenFinder = new Regex("(<form)[^>]*>");

    Match frmOpen = frmOpenFinder.Match(result);
    string frm = frmOpen.Value;
    result = result.Replace(frm, "").Replace("</form>", "");
}
```

But in this case, theForm is again

```
var theForm = document.forms['ctl00'];
    if (!theForm) {
        theForm = document.ctl00;
    }
```

But there isn't any form with such id and now I get:

```
theForm is undefined
```

exception.

Comment: `__EVENTTARGET` is set to the ClientID of the control that causes the PostBack. Every asp.net control passes these values to `__doPostBack`. You can inspect the html you are generating to see if this is happening correctly in your case.

Comment: I got this error when calling `<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>` in a legacy WebForms app that had MVC4 and jQuery added in.  Removing this bundle seemed to solve the problem, and I was able to keep the jquery/jqueryui/jqueryval bundles with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is still undefined. I have tested this too, and there is something wrong (at least when using ajax) where the clientID of a button control does not come back at the point of post back. Conversely, I also had an input field and a dropdown also cause a post back on the page and those two postbacks actually came back with the proper ID string. It is something with button control in specific.

Answer (score 1):

It may sound strange but ASP.NET could be mis-detecting IE 10 and 11. This will cause it to render a page with __doPostBack JavaScript errors.

A simple fix is to install .NET 4.5 on your server. If this is not possible (for example if it's Window Server 2003) then there are some hotfixes that can be installed to rectify the issue. Please refer to this site:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx